# DocumentDB SQL: SELECT Without Flattening Object?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have an IceCream document.

```
{
  "flavor": "Chocolate",
  "details": {
    "cone": true,
    "description": "super long string"
  }
}
```

I'd like to query just for the flavor and if it has a cone.

`SELECT c.flavor, c.details.cone FROM c`

But the object being returned is-

```
{
  "flavor": "Chocolate",
  "cone": true
}
```

I'd like to keep the original format where `cone` is a child of `details`. How is this possible with DocumentDB Sql?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the JSON within your DocumentDB query:

`SELECT VALUE { "flavor": c.flavor, "details": { "cone": c.details.cone } } FROM c`